# What feature of Windows 8.1 enables the Visual Studio Tasks Window to include details on async operations?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

A new feature of Visual Studio 2013 is that the Tasks Window includes all pending async tasks.  In the introduction [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/26/visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx), S. Somasegar says that this only works in Windows 8.1 due to changes in the OS.

> With all of the work we did for C# and Visual Basic in .NET 4.5 and
>   Visual Studio 2012 to enable more productive asynchronous programming,
>   I’m particularly excited about improvements we’ve made in this release
>   to support async debugging (you need to be using Visual Studio 2013 on
>   Windows 8.1 to get this capability, as the debugger relies in part on
>   some new operating system support to enable it).

Which new API does Windows 8.1 include?

Comment: Any number of changes that were introduced by the `.NET Framework 4.5.1` since not all of the documentation has not been released yet the specific changes are not known.

Comment: .Net 4.5.1 works on older Windows.  Tasks Window requires Windows 8.1 too.  I wonder what other stuff can be done with the new tasks api on Windows 8.1, in particular with native code.

Comment: It took me awhile to find the statement in question.  Its likely changes to the Win32 API itself.  Until additional information on the changes introduced with 8.1 are publish I am not sure this question can be answered.

Answer (score 3):

On the platform side, take a look at the Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics namespace. I believe some of the new Win8.1 platform pieces are in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.aspx

Ben

Comment: You can see the implementation of much of this logic in the wrl async.h header. As Ben pointed out, the root of the functionality is in the AsyncCausality class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.asynccausalitytracer.aspx